# Euclidean Geometry problem regarding the line passing through incenter

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

This is from the exercise problems(not the live contest) for regional math competition.

Let triangle $ABC$ satisfy $\angle C > 90^\circ$ and let its incenter be $I$. Let $\ell$ be the line parallel to $BC$ passing through $I$, and call $\ell \cap AB = D$, $\ell \cap BC = E$. We know that $AI = 3$ and the radius of inscribed circle of the triangle $ABC$ is $1$. Finally, $(\text{area of }ABC) = 5\sqrt{2}$ is given. The problem is to find $DE$.

Below is my attempt to do something but I am stuck. How can I proceed to get $DE$?

Thank you in advance for any form of help, hint, or solution.

[image]

Comment: A minor point (too minor to be suggested as an edit!), but you say that $\ell \cap BC = E$. This should be $AC$, as your diagram shows.

Answer (score 6):

In fact, your existing work almost solves the problem already.  The next step is to observe that the altitude $h_A$ from $A$ to $BC = x+y$ must satisfy
$$5 \sqrt{2} = |\triangle ABC| = \frac{1}{2} h_A (x+y) = \frac{3\sqrt{2}}{2} h_A,$$
hence $h_A = \frac{10}{3}$.  Then because $DE \parallel BC$ and the distance between them is $r = 1$, it follows from the similarity of triangles that
$$\frac{DE}{BC} = \frac{h_A - 1}{h_A} = \frac{7}{10},$$
therefore
$$DE = \frac{7}{10} \cdot 3 \sqrt{2} = \frac{21}{5 \sqrt{2}}.$$

Answer (score 3):

You've made a good start. Using your diagram, we have that

$$2\alpha + 2\beta + 2\gamma = 180^{\circ} \;\to\; \alpha + \beta + \gamma = 90^{\circ} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Thus, using your $x + y = 3\sqrt{2}$ result, plus the Pythagorean theorem to get $\lvert BI\rvert = \sqrt{1 + y^2}$ and $\lvert CI\rvert  = \sqrt{1 + x^2}$, results in

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\sin(\alpha + \beta) & = \sin(90^{\circ} - \gamma) \\
\sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta) + \cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta) & = \cos(\gamma) \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + y^2}}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}}\right) + \frac{y}{\sqrt{1 + y^2}}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}}\right) & = \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3} \\
x + y & = \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}(\sqrt{1 + x^2})(\sqrt{1 + y^2}) \\
3\sqrt{2} & = \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}(\sqrt{1 + x^2})(\sqrt{1 + y^2}) \\
\frac{9}{2} & = (\sqrt{1 + x^2})(\sqrt{1 + y^2}) \\
\frac{81}{4} & = (1 + x^2)(1 + y^2) \\
\frac{81}{4} & = 1 + x^2 + y^2 + x^2y^2 \\
x^2 + y^2 & = \frac{77}{4} - x^2y^2
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Squaring both sides of your $x + y = 3\sqrt{2}$ result gives that

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
x^2 + 2xy + y^2 & = 18 \\
\left(\frac{77}{4} - x^2y^2\right) + 2xy & = 18 \\
-x^2y^2 + 2xy + \frac{77}{4} - \frac{72}{4} & = 0 \\
(xy)^2 - 2xy - \frac{5}{4} & = 0
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

This is a quadratic equation in $xy$ so, using the quadratic formula and that $xy \gt 0$, we get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
xy & = \frac{2 \pm \sqrt{4 - 4\left(-\frac{5}{4}\right)}}{2} \\
& = \frac{2 \pm \sqrt{4 + 5}}{2} \\
& = \frac{2 \pm 3}{2} \\
& = \frac{5}{2}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Since $DI \parallel BC$, letting $F$ be the point where the vertical line from $I$ touches $AB$, we have $\measuredangle IDF = \measuredangle CBF = 2\alpha$. Thus, from $\triangle IDF$, we have

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\lvert DI\rvert & = \frac{1}{\sin(2\alpha)} \\
& = \frac{1}{2\sin(\alpha)\cos(\alpha)} \\
& = \frac{1}{2\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}\right)\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}\right)} \\
& = \frac{1 + y^2}{2y} \\
& = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{y} + y\right)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

Similarly, we get $\lvert IE\rvert = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x} + x\right)$. Adding these $2$ results, and using \eqref{eq4A}, gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\lvert DE\rvert & = \lvert DI\rvert + \lvert IE\rvert \\
& = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} + x + y\right) \\
& = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{y}{xy} + \frac{x}{xy} + x + y\right) \\
& = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{xy}(x + y) + (x + y)\right) \\
& = \frac{x + y}{2}\left(\frac{1}{xy} + 1\right) \\
& = \frac{3\sqrt{2}}{2}\left(\frac{2}{5} + 1\right) \\
& = \frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\frac{7}{5}\right) \\
& = \frac{21}{5\sqrt{2}}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$